# C++ several instances (but not all) of a class sharing a vector

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I want to have a class `C`, such that instances of `C` hold a `std::vector<int>` as a private member. Now many instances (but not all) of `C` will share that vector and keeping a copy for each instance is what I would want to avoid.

If this vector were a single integer for example, I could create a template class for `C` and have it like this:

```cpp
template <int N>
class C {
 // something
};
```

If instead of some instances I wanted all instances to share that vector then I would declare the variable static as

```cpp
class C {
    static std::vector<int> _vec;
```

What I am looking is for something intermediate. I could for example keep a `shared_ptr` as a private non-static member as in

```cpp
class C {
     std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>> _vec;
}
```

And that would take care of the lifetime of the object, with some overhead for maintaining shared ownership and also an extra pointer per-instance. I could keep a reference instead and let the creator of the instances take care of the lifetime, but avoid the overhead of the `shared_ptr`. Is there a better approach to this design question?

Comment: if you make it a template then it is not different instances of the same class, but `C<1>` is a different class than `C<2>`. You'd actually have all instances of one class "share" the same integer. However, that `int` cannot be modified, so I do not see how it is comparable to the other alternatives. Anyhow, there is too little details / background / requirements to say what would be a "better" design

Comment: I'm fine with having a `static const` instead of a static variable. And I'm fine with the template example if the vector were instead an `int`. If pointers or vectors were structural parameters I'd be happy to have the vector as a template parameter.

Comment: Could you have an otherwise meaningless template parameter just to differentiate the different vectors and then use a static data member after all?

Comment: I would use simple pointer if I can safely manage this vector outside of class, i.e. when its by design allocated before all instances of `C` and deallocated after all instances of `C` are destructed. And use `std::shared_ptr` in case when you can't have such guarantees. PS: Specifically in your case you can use simple pointer and statically allocated vector.

Comment: if you are fine with the template that means that the member can/should be `const` and that you need not a member that is shared among some instances of the *same* class. You should clarify that, because the solution with the smart pointer suggests that you want what you write: non-const, shared among some instances of the same class. But then it seems like its not what you want

Comment: Thanks @DavisHerring and @sklott for the messages both are useful: I think I can try to follow Davis' advice as I can probably write an injective function Z --> allowed vectors, so that probably I can use a template parameter `int`.

Answer (score 2):

> …such that instances of C hold a std::vector as a private member. Now many instances (but not all) of C will share that vector

So, that's self-contradicting. You can't hold an instance and share the instance safely.

This is a classical use case of pointers; even more specifically, classical use case of a *shared pointer*, as you already noticed.

> I could keep a reference instead and let the creator of the instances take care of the lifetime,

**/me sounds the access-after-destruction alarm** 
You're about to find out that won't work. The lifetime is not like you think, but ends when the owning object's lifetime ends. So, this breaks. (Also, you'll find that under the hood, handing out references compiles down to the same code as handing out raw pointers – it's just safer and does the dereferencing automagically within the language; you're not actually saving a memory indirection there. The classes containing the reference still need to know the address of the object they're handling, and that's the same as having a pointer, if you ask your CPU.)

It breaks, unless the thing handing out the references keeps a count on how many references it handed out, subtracts many references it handed out belong to `C` instances that were deconstructed, and then deconstructs the vector as soon as that number reaches 0. Take a wild guess what a `shared_ptr` does! Exactly this *reference counting*.

Often, however, the access logic is easier; for example,

> I have a vector of `C`, `std::vector<C> lexicon`, and all held `C._vec` need to get removed exactly when that full `lexicon` goes out of scope, so I handle that manually

actually doesn't need reference counting and hence is lower-overhead. You can indeed solve that by handing out references – but I'd actually prefer to hand out raw pointers in that case: they just as much don't imply ownership, and you don't accidentally make a copy of the `std::vector<int>` when you pass the pointer by value.

If your lifetime tracking isn't as easy as that example :

There's no magic usage tracking in references; and you need something to keep track of whether something is still holding some handle to your individual `vector`. That tracking is exactly the "overhead" `shared_ptr` incurs. No way around it.

A private `shared_ptr` is hence the right approach:

```
class C {
  private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>> _vec;
}
```

Your `static` approach takes you nowhere here - it only makes sense if *all*, and really all, instances share the same vector which should essentially live from the beginning of time till the end, and even then, it's a bit of a solution that can lead to additional headaches in form of the static initialization order fiasco. I'd advise to not do that under almost all circumstances.

(Plus, a `static` member also just boils down to the code looking up the same address – so, performance-wise, same as a pointer. Again, nothing really won here.)